# perf results show a lot of finish_task_switch and seems inconsistent with atop results

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, perf

I am trying to analyze CPU issues in my code.

(1) atop command shows my application typically taking similar amounts of USR and SYS CPU.
(2) however, if I look at my perf results, it looks like kernel totally dominates
(3) also, why does finish_task_switch dominate so much? What does this indicate?

**(1) atop results**

```
    PID      TID  SYSCPU   USRCPU   VGROW   RGROW   RUID      EUID      ST   EXC   THR  S   CPUNR   CPU   CMD        1/3
```

```
  70364        -   0.22s    0.34s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -    22  S       3    6%   g_Sclient_no_d
  70364    70364   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       3    0%   g_Sclient_no_d
  70364    70365   0.08s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    1%   g_Sclient_no_d
  70364    70366   0.01s    0.01s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       3    0%   recvonly:ice
  70364    70367   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       1    0%   recvonly:pc
  70364    70368   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       0    0%   appsrc0:src
  70364    70369   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    0%   gmain
  70364    70370   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    0%   queue2:src
  70364    70371   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       1    0%   rtpsession-rtc
  70364    70372   0.11s    0.08s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       3    2%   nicesrc0:src
  70364    70373   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       3    0%   nicesrc1:src
  70364    70374   0.05s    0.08s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    1%   queue0:src
  70364    70375   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       3    0%   queue1:src
  70364    70376   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    0%   dtlsenc0:src
  70364    70377   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    0%   dtlsenc1:src
  70364    70378   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    0%   GstSystemClock
  70364    70379   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    0%   SCTP iterator
  70364    70380   0.00s    0.06s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    1%   SCTP timer
  70364    70381   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    0%   sctpenc0:src
  70364    70382   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       0    0%   sctpdec0:src_1
  70364    70383   0.00s    0.02s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    0%   timer
  70364    70384   0.01s    0.06s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    1%   rtpjitterbuffe
  70364    70385   0.00s    0.00s    364K    264K   user      user      --     -     1  S       2    0%   pool-g_Sclient
```

**(2) perf results**

```
+   26.39%  nicesrc0:src     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] finish_task_switch                                                 ◆
+   12.30%  queue0:src       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] finish_task_switch                                                 ▒
+    9.01%  g_Sclient_no_de  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] finish_task_switch                                                 ▒
+    7.98%  SCTP timer       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] finish_task_switch                                                 ▒
+    5.99%  rtpjitterbuffer  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] finish_task_switch                                                 ▒
+    3.49%  recvonly:pc      g_Sclient_no_dec   [.] bn_mul_add_words                                                   ▒
+    1.75%  timer            [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] finish_task_switch                                                 ▒
+    1.19%  nicesrc0:src     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __lock_text_start                                                  ▒
+    1.11%  recvonly:pc      g_Sclient_no_dec   [.] bn_sqr_comba8                                                      ▒
+    1.03%  queue0:src       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __lock_text_start                                                  ▒
+    0.75%  queue0:src       g_Sclient_no_dec   [.] g_type_check_instance_is_fundamentally_a                           ▒
+    0.67%  rtpsession-rtcp  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] finish_task_switch                                                 ▒
+    0.52%  nicesrc0:src     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __softirqentry_text_start                                          ▒
     0.48%  nicesrc0:src     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] do_int80_syscall_32
```

Comment: What hardware, and what kind of user-space workload?  `do_int80_syscall_32` would seem to indicate that you have user-space code using the slow `int 0x80` was to invoke the 32-bit system call ABI (instead of calling into the VDSO for sysenter), in case that matters for overall performance.

Comment: @PeterCordes -- I'm running a 32-bit x86 binary in a Ubuntu 64 VM guest (vmware). I don't have a lot of experience with perf but was hoping it would point me to my highest CPU functions. Instead it keeps pointing to finish_task_switch, as if the highest CPU thing being done is context switching?

Comment: That's possible if all you're doing is piping data between processes, or sending it on a socket or something.  From the names of your tasks, that seems possible.